# Open a hyperlink to a pdf file from excel

Tags: pdf, hyperlink

I inserted a hyperlink to a pdf file in my excel table using `Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;` `write_url()` method. But when I want to open the link, it displays the pdf file as text rather than an image. Any ideas of how to open the link with original pdf image? Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like the client may not have the browser PDF viewer installed properly. A hyperlink is just that, a link to a document. You are probably doing that just fine, but the browser isn't interpreting the file served properly.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem sounds very much like the one I posted a couple of days ago - except mine was trying to hyperlink from excel to .jpgs in my website. You click on the Hyperlink and instead of getting an image you get a long page full of characters. This started to happen about March this year. Except it is fine with Firefox and Explorer.
I have spent most of my afternoon first with Mac - Safari and then with MS Excel group. Their conclusion is that it is a known bug between XL and Mac and they are still working on it.
I uploaded a .PDF to my web site (link is:  http://www.hkirbydesigns.com/PIDB/RocknGrass.pdf) and I was able to view the image with firefox but not with Safari - I got the characters with Safari. So, MS said to use a different browser until they have fixed the bug.
Hope this is useful.